# Change the uber eats order status through uber eats api

Tags: javascript, express, uber-api

Hi hope you all are doing very good i want to change the uber eats order delivery status from my app as i am in partnership whit uber eats for that purpose i am using [Update delivery status api](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v1/post-eats-orders-orderid-restaurantdelivery-status)

which require the scope of
***eats.store.orders.restaurantdelivery.status***
i am unable to generate a token with this scope how can i generate that token and what grant type i need i have not seen this scope in my developers dashboard and i have also not seen this scope in the uber eats documentation about the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the above-mentioned scope if you are a delivery partner with uber eats can then you can change the order status API